# PostgreSQL 9.3: Primary key violated by a trigger INSERT

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, trigger, transaction

### My problem

Consider a table `t` with many frequent updates from users, from which only the last few are relevant.

In order to keep the table size reasonable, whenever a new row is inserted old rows from the same `user_id` are deleted. In order to keep an archive, the row is also written to `t_history`.

Both `t` and `t_history` have the same schema, in which `id` is a `bigserial` with a primary key constraint.

### Implementation

#### Stored procedure

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION update_t_history()
RETURNS trigger
AS
$$
declare
BEGIN
    -- Insert the row to the t_history table. `id` is autoincremented
    INSERT INTO t_history (a, b, c, ...)
    VALUES (NEW.a, NEW.b, NEW.c, ...);

    -- Delete old rows from the t table, keep the newest 10 
    DELETE FROM t WHERE id IN (
                  SELECT id FROM t 
                  WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id 
                  ORDER BY id DESC
                  OFFSET 9);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Corresponding insertion trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER t_insertion_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON t
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_t_history();
```

#### The error

The trigger works well, but when I run a few dozen insertions in a single transaction, I get the following error:

```sql
BEGIN
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t_history_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(196) already exists.
```

### Updates

- The `id` field in both tables (from `\d+ t`):

  - `id|bigint|not null default nextval('t_id_seq'::regclass)`
  - `"t_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)`
- PostgreSQL version is 9.3.

**Any idea why the stored procedure breaks the primary key constraint in transactions?**

Comment: Multiple single-value `insert`s in one transaction, or a single multi-valued insert statement?

Comment: *Always* your version of Postgres, please. Also, how exactly is `t_history.id` autoincremented? Best provide the table definition you get with `\d tbl` in psql. And asre you sure you are not copying `t.id` in the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks! Updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is `t_history.id` auto-incremented in the first place? If *"both `t` and `t_history` have the same schema"*, and `t.id` is a serial PK, you can just copy whole rows.

I would also suggest you only copy rows you actually delete from `t` to `t_history` - in a data-modifying CTE. This way you do not have overlapping rows (which might be part of the problem).

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_t_history()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   -- Keep the newest 10, move older rows to t_history
   WITH del AS (
      DELETE FROM t
      USING (
         SELECT id
         FROM   t 
         WHERE  user_id = NEW.user_id 
         ORDER  BY id DESC
         OFFSET 10      -- to keep 10 (not 9)
         FOR UPDATE     -- avoid race condition
         ) d
      WHERE t.id = d.id
      RETURNING t.*
      )
   INSERT INTO t_history 
   SELECT * FROM del;   -- copy whole row

   RETURN NULL;         -- irrelevant in AFTER trigger
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The new row is already visible in an `AFTER` trigger.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I will try your solution and write you back.  I don't see how can we have overlapping rows on `INSERT`, because we `INSERT` the same row to both tables once, and `t` never had overlap issues.
BTW, I didn't know `FOR UPDATE` - will read about it.

Comment: @AdamMatan: Note, `RETURNING` was missing in my answer, added now.

Comment: @AdamMatan if the insert is done on both tables, then any update will have to be done on both as well. The deletes of course will be trivial.

Comment: I followed your advice, and simply added `id` and `NEW.id` to the `INSERT` statement in my code. It did the trick - I wonder why.